# Need help on JavaScript async and await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am working with JavaScript specially NodeJS but my async await idea is not much clear that's why I am facing some problem. See the code below first:

```
exports.scheduleDates = (req, res) => {
    let currentTime = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD')
    Schedules.findAll({
        attributes: ['disable_dates_array'],
    }).then(result => {
        let firstDay, secondDay
        let disableDates = JSON.stringify(result).substring(25, JSON.stringify(result).length - 3).split(',')

        let i = 0, found = false, addDay = 1
        function getFirstAvailableDay() {
            disableDates.map(v => {
                i += 1
                if (v == currentTime) {
                    currentTime = moment(new Date()).add(addDay, 'days').format('')
                    addDay += 1
                    i = 0
                    getFirstAvailableDay()
                }

                else if (i == disableDates.length - 1 && found == false) {
                    firstDay = currentTime
                }
            })
        }
        getFirstAvailableDay()
        let secDay = moment(new Date()).add(addDay, 'days').format('YYYY/MM/DD'); i = 0
        function getSecondAvailableDay() {
            disableDates.map(v => {
                i += 1
                if (v == secDay) {
                    secDay = moment(new Date()).add(addDay, 'days').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
                    sec += 1
                    i = 0
                    getSecondAvailableDay()
                }

                else if (i == disableDates.length - 1 && found == false) {
                    secondDay = secDay
                }
            })
        }

        getSecondAvailableDay()
        let fd = firstDay.replace(/\//g, '-'); let sd = secondDay.replace(/\//g, '-');
        firstDay = fd, secondDay = sd
        let response = {
            available_days: [
                firstDay,
                secondDay
            ],
        }

        sequelize
            .query("SELECT favourite_routes.passenger_id AS 'passenger_id', favourite_routes.route_id AS 'route_id', routes.trip_price as 'ticket_price', points.id as 'pick_up_point_id', points.name as 'pick_up_point_name', drop_off.id as drop_off_point_id, drop_off.name as 'drop_of_point_name', locations.id as 'pick_up_location_id', locations.name as 'pick_up_location_name', drop_off_location.id as 'drop_off_location_id', drop_off_location.name as 'drop_off_location_name' FROM ( favourite_routes LEFT JOIN points ON favourite_routes.pick_up_id = points.id LEFT JOIN points as drop_off ON favourite_routes.drop_of_id = drop_off.id LEFT JOIN routes ON favourite_routes.route_id = routes.id left JOIN locations ON points.location_id = locations.id LEFT JOIN locations as drop_off_location on drop_off.location_id = drop_off_location.id ) WHERE (favourite_routes.passenger_id = 14926)GROUP BY favourite_routes.id")
            .then(data => {
                response.favourite_route = data[0][0]
                let i = 0, times = [];
                response.available_days.map(day => {
                    sequelize.query(`SELECT DISTINCT times.time, times.id FROM bus_time_dates LEFT JOIN bus_times ON bus_time_dates.bus_time_id = bus_times.id LEFT JOIN locations ON bus_times.location_id = locations.id LEFT JOIN times ON bus_times.time_id = times.id WHERE bus_time_dates.date = '${day}' AND bus_times.location_id = ${response.favourite_route.pick_up_location_id}`).then(data => {
                        let date = {
                            date: day,
                            times: data[0]
                        }
                        times.push(date)
                    })
                })
                setTimeout(() => {
                    response.times = times
                    res.status(201).json({
                        "status": true,
                        "code": 200,
                        "message": "Success",
                        "data": response
                    })
                }, 5)
            })
    })
}
```

In this controller file there have several section based on DB query and one is depending on another.

When I am going to give a response, I have to wait some time because it takes some time to get the query result. But using async that will be more accurate.

How can I rewrite the full controller file using async and await function?

Comment: Async await is just a syntactic sugar as an alternative to the promise syntax. You don't necessarily need to refactor it but in case you want to, there are many articles on google which will point you in the right direction. You can also check this out https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions

Comment: thansk..@vatz88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you asked converted the Promises below. But its just an alternative to Promises. You dont have to re-write your code but anyways since you said you want to re-write pls find the async await version below.

```
exports.scheduleDates = async (req, res) => {
    let currentTime = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD')
    try{
        let result = await Schedules.findAll({
            attributes: ['disable_dates_array'],
        });
        let firstDay, secondDay
        let disableDates = JSON.stringify(result).substring(25, JSON.stringify(result).length - 3).split(',')

        let i = 0, found = false, addDay = 1
        function getFirstAvailableDay() {
            disableDates.map(v => {
                i += 1
                if (v == currentTime) {
                    currentTime = moment(new Date()).add(addDay, 'days').format('')
                    addDay += 1
                    i = 0
                    getFirstAvailableDay()
                }

                else if (i == disableDates.length - 1 && found == false) {
                    firstDay = currentTime
                }
            })
        }
        getFirstAvailableDay()
        let secDay = moment(new Date()).add(addDay, 'days').format('YYYY/MM/DD'); i = 0
        function getSecondAvailableDay() {
            disableDates.map(v => {
                i += 1
                if (v == secDay) {
                    secDay = moment(new Date()).add(addDay, 'days').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
                    sec += 1
                    i = 0
                    getSecondAvailableDay()
                }

                else if (i == disableDates.length - 1 && found == false) {
                    secondDay = secDay
                }
            })
        }

        getSecondAvailableDay()
        let fd = firstDay.replace(/\//g, '-'); let sd = secondDay.replace(/\//g, '-');
        firstDay = fd, secondDay = sd
        let response = {
            available_days: [
                firstDay,
                secondDay
            ],
        }

        let data = await sequelize .query("SELECT favourite_routes.passenger_id AS 'passenger_id', favourite_routes.route_id AS 'route_id', routes.trip_price as 'ticket_price', points.id as 'pick_up_point_id', points.name as 'pick_up_point_name', drop_off.id as drop_off_point_id, drop_off.name as 'drop_of_point_name', locations.id as 'pick_up_location_id', locations.name as 'pick_up_location_name', drop_off_location.id as 'drop_off_location_id', drop_off_location.name as 'drop_off_location_name' FROM ( favourite_routes LEFT JOIN points ON favourite_routes.pick_up_id = points.id LEFT JOIN points as drop_off ON favourite_routes.drop_of_id = drop_off.id LEFT JOIN routes ON favourite_routes.route_id = routes.id left JOIN locations ON points.location_id = locations.id LEFT JOIN locations as drop_off_location on drop_off.location_id = drop_off_location.id ) WHERE (favourite_routes.passenger_id = 14926)GROUP BY favourite_routes.id")
        response.favourite_route = data[0][0]
        let i = 0, times = [];
        response.available_days.map(day => {
            sequelize.query(`SELECT DISTINCT times.time, times.id FROM bus_time_dates LEFT JOIN bus_times ON bus_time_dates.bus_time_id = bus_times.id LEFT JOIN locations ON bus_times.location_id = locations.id LEFT JOIN times ON bus_times.time_id = times.id WHERE bus_time_dates.date = '${day}' AND bus_times.location_id = ${response.favourite_route.pick_up_location_id}`).then(data => {
                let date = {
                    date: day,
                    times: data[0]
                }
                times.push(date)
            })
        })
        response.times = times
        res.status(201).json({
            "status": true,
            "code": 200,
            "message": "Success",
            "data": response
        })
    }catch(error){
        //console.log(error)
    }
}
```